# php External function call not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, external

I'm not sure if this question will require some code examples, but...

Here's the situation:

I am working on a site that someone else has already done work on.
I am trying to call an external function located in a file, let's aay, 'myFunctions.php'.
The previous person has function calls to this file in the main web page with no problem.
I created a new short function and placed it in that same file.
The web page already has a 'require_once("myfunctions.php");' line.
The web site is in Wordpress, though a highly customized site.
The new function works fine when placed in the page, however I would like to use it on more than one page.

How can I get the new function to work?  Does it have something to do with Wordpress?

It seems strange to me because the other functions that were already in the file work with no problem.

Thank you.

---

Next test:

It seems the problem is in the calling somehow.

I simplified the code in order to test this.  Here is the code I have now:

```
<?php
$user = getUserInfo($username);
$myTest = strTest();

echo $myTest;
?>
```

And in the external functions file funct.php:

```
<?php

function strTest(){
   return "This test worked!";
}

?>
```

The above function "getUserInfo" is a older one that also resides in the funct.php and works just fine.

However, the new function "strTest", when called does not work and the page is blank from that line on.

---

Update!

Found it!

Sorry to everyone who contributed, but it looks like it was just a stupid oversight.  I had just realized that the other guy had the functions containing file in another folder.  There was a copy of it in the folder I was working with, but the actual 'include' statement referred to the other folder.

As with many problems I've had before, when the results seem very strange, the problem is usually syntax or address errors.

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need some source code here. Is the function putted inside a class?

Comment: The function returns a string used like this:

Comment: The function returns a string and is called like this:  $myString = getNewString($param);    I actually just tried to copy an existing function, with only changing the names.  It didn't work.  Also, I couldn't find any particular class declaration from the other guy's code.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by didn't work? Is there any error message?
You might want to use this function to check if "getNewString" exists
http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Move it to `functions.php` in stylesheet directory. All WP scripts will be able to call it.

Comment: Tried that as well.  Didn't work.  The page just crashes at the call line.

Comment: OK. That was the obvious answer. Could you post the function?

Comment: I tried to simplify it by just reducing the function down to:   function getString () { return 'testing string';}   needless to say, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Most WP projects have at least one *header file*; if you call the function file from within any of these header files, it will be available to all the pages inheriting the header file. 
 
Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more details.